# Python net activity statistics linux

Tags: python, linux

What is the easiest way to get network statistics (bandwidth used, current down/up rate) via Python.

I realize it'll have to be a system call to /proc, but is there an easier way or some tool that is available on standard *nix distributions for doing so?

Thanks

NOTE: I am going to use /proc/net/dev and parse the output 8-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynetinfo/ - it would need extending to get the statistics, but that should be fairly trivial. Most of the code is already in place.

Alternatively you can just parse the output of `ip -s link show device_name`

Comment: Awesome, the only thing I'm missing is the current up/down rate. Do I need to calculate that myself? If so, thats fine, just was wondering if this was already in place or not

Comment: You'll need to calculate it yourself, since "current rate" does not really exist unless you define a period for the measurement. Most software simply polls the values often. (avoid forking `ip` every time if you do want to poll the values quite often - `ioctl()` is the right way to go in this case) Also you can call ioctl from python itself if you don't want to write C. But the interface is at least tricky... http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html

Comment: Thanks! I plan on forking pynetinfo and adding the information myself.